# Using a Moq object in a WCF Service (server side i.e. not client side)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, moq

Please see the code below, which is the Service Layer of an application:

```
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
    {
        public ChangeCalculator Add(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            calculator.Calculate(number1, number2);
            return calculator;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to understand how I would unit test this WCF service using NUnit and MOQ.  I thought about injecting the Calculator dependency. However, interfaces cannot be serialised.  How would I unit test this function using MOQ as the Mocking framework?

Comment: First ask yourself "What would I want to check as behaving as expected in the above method/function and would have knock-on effects of not mocked out as a dependency"

Comment: Is this actual code or just an example. The service doesn't make much sense to me functionality wise. What would its purpose be?

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks.  I am trying to understand the role of a service layer in a multi tier app and this is what I have come with so far (it is not the real app).  The service layer would expose functions like: Add, Subtract; Multiply and Divide to multiple clients (where the clients are on different platforms e.g. .net, Java etc).  Why does it not make much sense?

Comment: the calculator is being used as a dependency to perform some action but is then being returned like a model. I would have expected it to do something like `return calculator.Result;` after the add. Not return the calculator itself. That is just my initial assessment of the code example presented. I may not have the full context behind its use.

Comment: In its current state there is no need to mock anything here if creating an instance of calculator has no adverse effects. create an instance of the service call the method under test and assert the expected results. done.

Comment: @Nkosi, The Calculator object contains many fields (some objects and some collections of objects).  Does it make sense now why I have returned a Calculator object to the client? Thanks again.

Comment: In order for this to work, the client would need to recognize the `Calculator` type in order to deserialize the response returned from the WCF service. But if the client recognizes `Calculator` then why would it call the service instead of just doing `new Calculator().Calculate(number1, number2)` itself? But in direct answer to your question - MOQ doesn't fit into this scenario.

Comment: @Scott Hannen, Calculate would have to return a 'this' object.  This does not sound right?

Comment: It the local application had an instance then the calculator wouldn't need to return an instance because the application would already have it.

Comment: Why does `However, interfaces cannot be serialised` prevent you from injecting the dependency into your service? What IoC technique did you use? How do you host the server?

Comment: @Nkosi there is a bit of a moot point with the intent of the code demonstrated by the OP. It doesn't so much matter if creating a service object has adverse effectsor not, it adds two concerns to the same method: creation of the service and execution of the operation. Creation of the service is best delegated to the central point in the application allowing for cleaner code and refactoring. E.g. if the OP has also a `Divide()` method or similar they'd need to refactor both (all...) if the Calculator or it's constructor signatures ever changed.

Comment: If the method is really as simple as `a +b` it can be made static and tested in isolation.